# File path or file descriptor for ARM execute system call

Tags: arm

I would like to retrieve the name of the executable file when an ARM "execute" system call is performed at runtime.

It may help to know how an "execute" system call is translated in ARM assembly. I would know the register where the file name is stored and retrieve it at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you assuming in your inquiry? I assume you are specifically referring to <syscall name="execve" number="11"/>.

Comment: @InfinitelyManic Yes, I am referring to the system call number 11. The OS is Android 6.0.1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This example illustrates a simple use of execu in ARMv7.

Assumes you have a simple file contain some text to sort.

The man page indicates that placement of the pointer to the executable. In my example "/bin/sh" is the executable.

So you are looking for an array structure pointer at R0.

```
NAME
       execve - execute program

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[],
                  char *const envp[]);

DESCRIPTION
       execve() executes the program pointed to by filename.  filename must be either a binary executable, or a script starting with a line of the form:

           #! interpreter [optional-arg]

       For details of the latter case, see "Interpreter scripts" below.

       argv  is  an array of argument strings passed to the new program.  By convention, the first of these strings should contain the filename associated with the file being executed.
       envp is an array of strings, conventionally of the form key=value, which are passed as environment to the new program.  Both argv and envp must be terminated by a null  pointer.
       The argument vector and environment can be accessed by the called program's main function, when it is defined as:

           int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])

       execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program loaded.
```

Sample code:

```
.data
        _filename:      .string "/bin/sh"
        arg0:           .string "/bin/sh"
        arg1:           .string "-c"
        arg2:           .string "sort -n myfile.txt"
        args:
                .word arg0
                .word arg1
                .word arg2
.text
        .global  main
main:
        bl _work

_work:
        push {lr}
        mov r7, #11             // execve syscall
        ldr r0,=_filename
        ldr r1,=args
        svc #0
        pop {pc}
```

Simple text file:

```
  $ cat myfile.txt
        9
        1
        5
        233
        5
        6
        723
        91
        0
        3
        2
        4576
        557
        6
        353
        3553
```

output example:

```
 $ ./simple_exec
0
1
2
3
5
5
6
6
9
91
233
353
557
723
3553
4576
```

Comment: It seems like the filename is stored in r0. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @Giuseppe - I think's it's a pointer since, among other reason, the file name length could exceed the size of the register. But you are on the right track.

Comment: Could you run different executable files and check if the file name is always loaded in r0?

Comment: Or even tell me how you printed out the assembly code

Comment: @Giuseppe - I wrote the Assembly code from scratch.  If I do '_filename:      .string "/usr/bin/top"' , the assembled code will issue the shell top command.  What language are you using in this case?

Comment: I am using C inside the Android Linux kernel. I would like to see the reverse. From C code to assembly code to check whether the file name is always loaded inside r0.

Comment: @Giuseppe ok - have you tried something like "objdump -d -M intel -S <file>.o" or "gcc -O2 -S <file>.c" to view the assembly code?

Comment: It should be slightly different for arm architecture right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138569/discussion-between-infinitelymanic-and-giuseppe).