# how do I make a syscall 11 (execve) in arm?

Tags: arm

Here's my code:

```
@execve takes 3 arguments (r0,r1,r2)

mov r7,#11 @syscall number for execve
ldr r0,=addr_of_string
sub r1,r1,r1 @so that r1 can get zero 
sub r2,r2,r2 @same for r2
svc #0

end:
mov r7,#1
svc 0

.data
addr_of_string: .asciz "\bin\ls"
```

It compiles successfully and links successfully but when I execute it, I get :

A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call

Comment: What operating system?  From looking at the code, it seems to be a 32-bit variety.  And judging we are using `svc 0`, I am guessing a Linux variety?  I'm no expert here, but having that info should help someone else answer the question easier.  Also, I'd expect a simple load of #0 into `r1` and `r2`, not this subtraction fun, but to each their own I guess.

Comment: See if this doesn't help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906569/file-path-or-file-descriptor-for-arm-execute-system-call

Comment: Yes sir.. It's Linux on arm v7..

Comment: If you follow the info from the link I gave, can you get your exec function to work properly?

Comment: In my case..
r0 = "/bin/ls"
r1 = 0
r2 = 0
r7 = #11

But then too..its not working

Comment: Then, I need to leave it to someone with a bit deeper knowledge than I here.

Comment: No problem..thanks for the effort,man :)

Answer (score 0):

[Why can the execve system call run "/bin/sh" without any argv arguments, but not "/bin/ls"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673765/why-can-the-execve-system-call-run-bin-sh-without-any-argv-arguments-but-not)

The above thread says that since /bin/ls is a part of gnu coreutils package and they call 'set' [program name] to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

[Why can the execve system call run "/bin/sh" without any argv arguments, but not "/bin/ls"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673765/why-can-the-execve-system-call-run-bin-sh-without-any-argv-arguments-but-not)

The above thread says that since /bin/ls is a part of the gnu coreutil package and it has to be setup before calling.